# How to create rig for space rover?

Tags: rigging

I am working on a space rover and I want to rig that thing.
I never rig car or some mechanical parts so I am struggling with that.
It should be pretty easy for someone with rigging knowledge, do you have some idea how to create rig for this.
Thanks for advice.
(there is only one "leg" on the image, it need to be mirrored on both sides)
[image]